# Deluge Windows to windows remote

Tags: windows, bittorrent, deluge

I have deluge installed on my home media center and than I have deluge installed on my main laptop.

I'm trying to remote the media center deluge. But nothing seems to be working.
In the connection manager I just get the red Dot.

The docs for windows are very poor over at deluged wiki
http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient

Has anyone been able to remote windows to window on deluge?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that you are running the same version of Deluge locally and on your media centre (minor versions shouldn't make a difference, but it helps eliminate any issues).

Then make sure the daemon is running - if you go into the *Connection Manager* on the media centre's Deluge you can click **Start Daemon** and try connect locally (you may have to turn off *Classic Mode* under *Preferences -> Interface* before you can do this).

Once you can connect locally, in *Preferences -> Daemon*, make sure **Allow Remote Connections** is enabled, and ensure the *Daemon Port* is allowed through the firewall ([instructions for Windows](http://support.lexisnexis.com/us_en_us/record.asp?bRFS=1&ArticleID=10101)).

Also make sure you forward the port to your media centre on your router (if you're unsure how to do this, reply with your router make/model and I'll try find instructions). Remember to do this for the WebUI's port number if you also want to run that (*Preferences -> WebUI*), but try get normal connections working first.

Once it works, in the *Connection Manager* click **Stop Daemon**. Then you can run *deluged.exe* as a service or a scheduled task (I prefer as a service, as you can quickly restart if it there's a problem).

Let me know if you want me to expand on anything here and I'll add more information on my setup (mine's running on Server 2012 Essentials as a service, connecting from a Windows 8 client).

Comment: I have Deluge set as a Task on my Win7 PC. How would I go about setting it as a Service? What exactly is the difference, since it is the same program?

Comment: There's not much difference between running it as a task or a service if you configure your task to run when the computer starts and to run in the background, but I find it a little easier to manage if there are issues (a restart of the service usually does the job).

If you want to create a service for it, you can try [SrvStart](http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/), though I personally use [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/), which is a paid product but has some additional features I use for other services.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to edit the auth config file (%appdata%\deluge) to add the necessary username, password, and authentication level before I could connect. Format is

```
<username>:<password>:<auth level>
```

From: http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Authentication